# Why is the GSpread RGB Color Scheme Inaccurate?

Tags: python, colors, rgb, gspread, keyboard-python

I am working on a project where I am trying to create a Pong-like game in Google sheets, using the spread library. However, I am not sure if this is a glitch, but the color coding of GSpread seems to be off.

---

```
    import gspread
    from gspread_formatting import *
    import contextlib
    import keyboard

    gc = gspread.service_account(filename=r'C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\GoogleSheetsGame\SuperSecretKey.json')
    sh = gc.open('Video Game')

    #Google Sheets Init

    mainworksheet = sh.worksheet("Game")
    fmt = cellFormat(backgroundColor=color(241, 194, 50))

    print('Ready!')
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('right arrow'):
            format_cell_range(mainworksheet, 'BI39:BI41', fmt)
```

---

I am going for a yellowish color, yet only get a dark blue in response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Got it! Turns out all colors have to be divided by 255 in order to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was starting to go a little crazy! How do you came with this solution?